# Angular 5 ng-select edit selected item

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multi-select

I am using ng-select in my ionic application so that user can select multiple email address in a textarea.

[image]

I want to edit selected email address by tapping/clicking on the tile. Once user tap/click on the selected email address, email address should append in textbox in editable mode.